# Upload file onto Server from the IPhone using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: php, iphone, upload, asihttprequest

I've been trying to upload a file (***login.zip***) using the ASIHTTPRequest libraries from the IPhone onto the inbuilt Apache Server in Mac OS X Snow Leopard. My code is:

```
 NSString *urlAddress = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:self.uploadField.text]autorelease];

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

 ASIFormDataRequest *request;  

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  
 NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"login.zip"];

 NSData *data = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:dataPath] autorelease];  

 request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];  
 [request setPostValue:@"login.zip" forKey:@"file"];  
 [request setData:data forKey:@"file"];
 [request setUploadProgressDelegate:uploadProgress];
 [request setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
 [request setDelegate:self];
 [request startAsynchronous];
```

The php code is :

```
<?php $target = "upload/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
$ok=1; 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{ echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded"; } 
else 
{ echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; } ?>
```

I don't quite understand why the file is not uploading. If anyone could help me. I've stuck on this for 5 days straight.

Thanks in advance
Nik

Comment: Did you get how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
[request setFile:filePath forKey:@"file"];
```

or if you can put your zip file into NSData like this

```
NSData *zipData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:zipName];
```

and send it to server with

```
[request setData:zip forKey:@"file"];
```

on the server try this

```
<?php




      $dir = "/var/www/your_directory/";

      $path = $dir . $_FILES['file']['name'];

      //move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path);


     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path))  {
                //return ok! :)
    }
     else {
      // return -> echo"There's been a problem uploading your file. Please try again";
    }   
?>
```

in `$_FILES['file']['name']` the `['file']` MUST be the same as `forKey:@"file"` in your request

Answer (score 0):

Is there a mismatch in the field names you're using?

It looks like you're using "file" on the iphone:

```
[request setPostValue:@"login.zip" forKey:@"file"];
```

but 'uploaded' on the server:

```
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ;
```

Try changing these to be the same.

Comment: What happens? Are there any errors in the server log file? Does the data get sent to the server?

Comment: No error on Error log. Access log reads "152.96.15.90 - - [22/Jul/2010:13:31:57 +0200] "POST /test/upload.php HTTP/1.1" 200 561
" i don't understand and it's driving me insane. :( :((