# Upload files from IPhone/IPad to mysql DB?

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, ios, upload

I've been searching a lot about managing data on IOS and finally i build an app that downloads PDF archives,when the user download a PDF the archive is displayed on a UITableView and the user can see the PDF.Now i need do to the most important thing to my project,upload those archives to my MYSQL DB!I've found an very busy tutorial on a website,but the app just upload images,so if anyone know,how can i upload PDF archives!Any tutorial or idea will be helpful!
Thanks in advanced!

PHP SCRIPT:

```
<?php
// Check if a file has been uploaded
if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
    // Make sure the file was sent without errors
    if($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0) {
        // Connect to the database
        $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'fileUP');
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        // Gather all required data
        $name = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
        $mime = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['type']);
        $data = $dbLink->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES  ['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));
        $size = intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size']);

        // Create the SQL query
        $query = "
            INSERT INTO `file` (
                `name`, `mime`, `size`, `data`, `created`
            )
            VALUES (
                '{$name}', '{$mime}', {$size}, '{$data}', NOW()
            )";

        // Execute the query
        $result = $dbLink->query($query);

        // Check if it was successfull
        if($result) {
            echo 'Success! Your file was successfully added!';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Error! Failed to insert the file'
               . "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'An error accured while the file was being uploaded. '
           . 'Error code: '. intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']);
    }

    // Close the mysql connection
    $dbLink->close();
}
else {
    echo 'Error! A file was not sent!';
}

// Echo a link back to the main page
echo '<p>Click <a href="form.php">here</a> to go back</p>';
?>
```

Comment: You ask for a tutorial. How about SEARCHING stack overflow? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Upload+files+IPhone+to+mysql+DB%3F

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following library to upload your PDF documents: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Comment: i've tried but nothing happens!Is possible to work with php scripts?Like i select the file and a UIActionSheet appears,so i select the PDF and click on upload,i request is send to a php script and the file is uploaded!Is this possible?I'm confused with these kind of problems,if you know any tutorial please post the link!

Comment: Yes, post the PDF file to a PHP script.  The PHP script should then handle the insert into the MySQL database.

Comment: I using an normal php script to post the file on a pc,the user click on 'select file' and a window is displayed,but this don't work on iPhone,so i kind of lost on how to execute my idea,i should add and action to the 'didSelectedRowAtIndex' and there i execute the php code?

Comment: Could you post the code that you are referring to?  Also, have you looked at the following post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300852/upload-file-onto-server-from-the-iphone-using-asihttprequest

Comment: Is your PHP code acting as a Web service or is it local on your PC whereby you are trying to call your localhost from the simulator?  The PHP script must be a Web service on a server.

Comment: i've just gave you an example of code,i very confused!Do you know any tutorial or source,uploading files from IOS!